# jQuery clearinterval / stopinterval doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval, clearinterval

I have an autorefresh function that gets called if a checkbox is checked and a button clicked. I want to stop the autorefresh when the checkbox is unclicked:

```
var refreshId = null; 

$("#disINFRAlive").click(function(infralivefun) {
    event.preventDefault(infralivefun);

    var category_id = {};
    category_id['datumanf'] = $("#datumanf").datepicker().val();
    category_id['datumend'] = $("#datumend").datepicker().val();

    $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to display.php
        type: "POST",
        url: "infratestomc.php?id=" + Math.random(),
        dataType: "html",      
        data: category_id,
        success: function(response) {
            $("#resulttabelle").show().html(response);
        }
    });

    if ($('#autorefcheck').is(':checked')) {
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            var category_id = {};
            category_id['datumanf'] = $("#datumanf").datepicker().val();
            category_id['datumend'] = $("#datumend").datepicker().val();

            $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to display.php
                type: "POST",
                url: "infratestomc.php?id=" + Math.random(), 
                dataType: "html",
                data: category_id,
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#resulttabelle").show().html(response);
                }
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

The autorefresh works if the checkbox #autorefcheck is checked and the button #disINFRAlive is clicked. However, I can't make it stop by unchecking the checkbox:

```
function stopinterval(){
  clearInterval(refreshId); 
  return false;
}

$('#autorefcheck').click(function() {
    stopinterval();
});
```

I tried to use clearInterval in various ways and none worked so far.

Comment: The `refreshId` inside your function isn't the same as the global one, because you declare it to be local to the function.

Comment: replace `var refreshId = setInterval(` by `refreshId = setInterval(` without `var`

Comment: @Yoplaboom thank you so much, this worked!!

Comment: @MinusFour thank you too, this was it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `var` keyword from the initialization of `refreshId`.

```
if ($('#autorefcheck').is(':checked')) {
    refreshId = setInterval(function() {
```

The way you have it, you are redeclaring the variable in a different scope. That way, you cannot access it from `stopInterval()`.